# Objective-c using thread causes: target does not implement selector

Tags: objective-c

As I am pretty new to ObjC I'm stuck to the following issue:

I have a function downloadFile

```
-(void) downloadFile:(NSMutableArray*)paramArray withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options      
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I want to start this as a thread, and therefore I use this line of code:

```
NSThread* dLoad = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadFile:) object:nil];
[dLoad start];
```

It throws me the following error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** -[LaunchDownload downloadFile:])'
```

What am I missing over here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're not providing enough arguments to your thread. The method you implemented has the signature `downloadFile:withDict:`, but you're only providing `downloadFile:`. You should give it the correct selector name.

Keep in mind that you will probably run into trouble anyway - the [NSThread class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) specifies that methods you call this way must take only one argument. I'd recommend either converting your two arguments to a single NSDictionary that your method parses out or rethinking how you're dispatching this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The method name is `downloadFile:withDict:` and not downloadFile: .